# How to set and get property in an angular 1 service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following type of angular 1 service. I'm trying to create getter and setter method to get access to a variable from different controllers.
But when I console.log the variable in the get method, it is undefined.

This service is inherited with the project. How could I create these methods in this way? Thanks.

```js
;(function(){
    angular.module( "MeetingApp" )
        .factory( 'history', history );

    history.$inject = [ '$http' ];
    
     function history( $http ){
        var historyService = {
        //other methods
          createHistory: createHistory
         setWeeklyMeetingId: setWeeklyMeetingId,
       getWeeklyMeetingId: getWeeklyMeetingId
      }
      
      function setWeeklyMeetingId(id) {
   this.weeklyMeetingId = id;
  }

  function getWeeklyMeetingId() {
 
   return this.weeklyMeetingId;
  }

        return historyService;
    };

}());
```

Updated:
First and second controllers have different views.
In the first controller I have:

```js
history.generateNewWeeklyMeeting(projectOrproduct)
    .then(meeting => {
     history.setWeeklyMeetingId(meeting.id);
      console.log('id',history.getWeeklyMeetingId()); //here I get the id
     return meeting;
    })
    .then(meeting => {
     location.href = siteURL + "/new-team-meeting";
    });
```

In the second controller:

```js
vm.WeeklyMeetingID = history.getWeeklyMeetingId();
console.log('get the id', history.getWeeklyMeetingId()) //Here it is undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. see this sample.

```js
app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,history) {
  history.setWeeklyMeetingId(10);
});
app.controller("myCtrl2", function($scope,history) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.WeeklyMeetingID = history.getWeeklyMeetingId();
});

app.factory('history', history);

history.$inject = ['$http'];

function history($http) {
  var historyService = {
    setWeeklyMeetingId: setWeeklyMeetingId,
    getWeeklyMeetingId: getWeeklyMeetingId
  }

  function setWeeklyMeetingId(id) {
    this.weeklyMeetingId = id;
  }

  function getWeeklyMeetingId() {
    return this.weeklyMeetingId;
  }

  return historyService;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">


  </div>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl2 as vm">
    {{vm.WeeklyMeetingID}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to set the value from one controller and get the value in another controller. In the first controller I use: `history.setWeeklyMeetingId(meeting.id);` and in the second - `vm.WeeklyMeetingID = history.getWeeklyMeetingId();
    console.log('get the id', vm.WeeklyMeetingID)` - Here it is undefined. I've injected the service.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether you run vm.WeeklyMeetingID = history.getWeeklyMeetingId(); after you run that set method? Maybe you run get before you set it. As you call set inside a asynchronous call it takes sometime to get the response and run inside.